# How to locate file path to original layers from feature layers in AGOL web map?

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, file-path

I was given an AGOL web map that was created by someone else within my organization that is no longer here, and I have no idea where the original editable layers in the web map exist on our network that were published to this web map. Is there a way in AGOL to see the original file paths for published feature layers? I want to be able to bring in the live data from this web map into future mxds and not have to just export the data as shapefiles from the web map.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to see an actual file path to each feature that has been published. When these layers are published as a service they must be within an ArcMap document (as I'm sure you are aware). When looking in the Content section of your ArcGIS Online, the title of the Service Definition may give you some keywords that you can search for in your windows explorer in hopes of finding the saved .mxd somewhere.

Another option that may give you some info is if the person who published these layers provided any notes in the metadata of these features.

One last option may be to select the feature service you would like to find, and take note of the created date.  In your Windows Explorer search bar, enter the date it was created (YYYY-MM-DD), and see if you can find the .mxd!